# MySQL query failed to run - MySQL error: #1064

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm getting the error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ' dag = zaterdag, start = 15, start_minuten = 00, eind = 19,
>   eind_minuten = 00, d' at line 1

when I try to run this query in Phpmyadmin:

`SELECT * FROM rooster WHERE medewerker = 00126311, dag = zaterdag, start = 15, start_minuten = 00, eind = 19, eind_minuten = 00, datum = 2016-09-17, weeknummer = 37, leiding = 0`

My table (rooster) structure:

```
id int(4)
medewerker varchar(10)
dag varchar(10)
start varchar(25)
start_minuten varchar(25)
eind varchar(25)
eind_minuten varchar(25)
datum date
weeknummer int(2)
leiding int(1)
```

medewerker is inner joined with another table, it shows the employee's number.

translation:
zaterdag means saturday
medewerker means employee
dag means day
minuten means minutes
datum means date
weeknummer mean weeknumber
leiding means boss (if boss is 1, he's the boss on that day)

I will appreciate it if someone could help me with this problem.

Comment: Use `AND` (or `OR`) between the WHERE clauses conditions, instead of commas!

Comment: But then it says, unknown column 'zaterdag' in 'where clause'. I typed this: SELECT * FROM rooster WHERE medewerker = 00126311 AND dag = zaterdag AND start = 15 AND start_minuten = 00 AND eind = 19 AND eind_minuten = 00 AND datum = 2016-09-17 AND weeknummer = 37 AND leiding = 0

Comment: if you want to query for strings, use parentheses: `AND dag = "zaterdag"`. This is not needed for integers.

Comment: Thanks MichielB, it works now. Since I can't label comments as answer, I'll label Suraz's answer as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try with this: you also have to enclose values in single quotes if datatype is VARCHAR or CHAR

```
SELECT * 
FROM rooster 
WHERE medewerker = '00126311' 
    AND dag = 'zaterdag'
    AND start = '15'
    AND start_minuten = '00'
    AND eind = '19'
    AND eind_minuten = '00' 
    AND datum = '2016-09-17'
    AND weeknummer = 37 
    AND leiding = 0
```

Comment: You can vote and choose the best if this is helpful anyways.

Comment: @Gordon it's very very important change.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

TripleDeal - in your WHERE clause, use AND operator instead of comma's

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but like I said to jarlh. I'm getting another error.
Unknown column 'zaterdag' in 'where clause'.
SELECT * FROM rooster WHERE medewerker = 00126311 AND dag = zaterdag AND start = 15 AND start_minuten = 00 AND eind = 19 AND eind_minuten = 00 AND datum = 2016-09-17 AND weeknummer = 37 AND leiding = 0